# Ektron: Change taxonomy of content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, taxonomy, ektron

I have a bunch of content items in Ektron that all have taxonomies assigned to them. I'm trying to write a method that will update the taxonomies based on a spreadsheet, where each row in the spreadsheet has the ID of a content item and the updated taxonomies that should be assigned to it. So, I have the content ID and the taxonomy IDs, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

What method do I use to change the taxonomies of my content items?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ContentManager class in order to update the taxonomies for a given item.

Here you have an example about how to retrieve already assigned taxonomies:
https://developer.ektron.com/forums/?v=t&t=3033

I guess what you need is:

Get all assigned taxonomies

```
var contentManager = new ContentManager(ApiAccessMode.Admin);
var taxonomyDataList = contentManager.GetAssignedTaxonomyList(contentId, language);
```

Remove those taxonomies from the item (iterating the previous list)

```
contentManager.RemoveTaxonomy(contentId, taxonomyId);
```

Assign the new taxonomy, coming from the excel document.

```
contentManager.AssignTaxonomy(contentId, taxonomyId);
```

**NOTES:**

- It is important to instantiate your ContentManager with *Admin* mode in order to update whatever content you have in your system, no matter the permissions they have.
- You need to execute this within a context of a Web Request. If you build a console application and reference Ektron binaries, that probably won't work as many methods rely on a HttpContext.